# NVIDIA Drivers problem with MX 150 in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, suspend

I have the Nvidia MX 150 graphics card in my Asus S15 Vivobook running Kubuntu 18.04.

After I install the Nvidia graphics driver, everything runs great except that the system does not wake up after sleep. I have tried multiple versions of the driver, from 340 up to 390, but none of these fixes the problem. I have tried all the fixes I have found on different sites, like updating grub, updating the kernel, and a few other hacks.  Unfortunately nothing works. Maybe it's an issue with my MX150 graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Kubuntu 18.10 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

> Suspend/Hibernation
>   If you use an old NVIDIA driver, hibernation and/or suspend may not
>   work. Here is a potential work around:
>
> We need to edit xorg.conf, open a terminal and enter the following
>   command:
>
> gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf In the section called Section "Device"
>   add Option "NvAGP" "1", you should end up with something like this:
>
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier     "my id"
>       Driver         "my dr"
>       VendorName     "my vendor"
>       BoardName      "my board name"
>       Option         "NvAGP" "1"
>
> EndSection Blacklist the intel_agp module from being loaded by the
>   kernel. This is done by editing blacklist.conf, open a terminal and
>   type:
>
> gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf Then add the following
>   line:
>
> blacklist intel_agp Reboot your system.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia?action=show&redirect=NvidiaLaptopBinaryDriverSuspend#Suspend.2BAC8-Hibernation

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try this. Updating to kubuntu 18.10 fixed my problem. Thanks anyways.